# Identify dependent or independent blocks of time series (clusters)

Tags: time-series, independence, pearson-r, spearman-rho, extreme-value

maybe I am lost in translation but I need your help.

**Description:** Having long time series of two variables I create some blocks (or clusters) with the method of peak over threshold but I need to check them if they are independent or not. The use of term "independence" is used in order to understand if the blocks are different to each other or they have many similarities according their variables in order to unify them to one block, I think that this procedure has already an application for floods and precipitation but I dont find a specific test or methodology.

**Question:**  Do you know how to check this independence? or 
How is the right term about this procedure, because the most common "independence between two variables" is not what I exactly mean above?

**Previous Work:** I am trying to view this independence by estimating Spearman and Kendall coefficients but I am not so satisfied with my results.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Question Update:

The **declustering** method solves this problem in extreme value theory. For more details see Coles (2001) *'An introduction to statistical modelling of extreme values'*